# Как правильно настроить Route в Laravel проекте?

Tags: php, laravel

При обращении на http://localhost/about я получаю 404 не найдено , знаком с данной ошибкой но не пойму каких настроек у меня не хватает ?

При попытке перехода в папку с `routes > web.php` в браузере по пути 
http://localhost/conlineltd/routes/web.php я получаю ошибку:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route' not found
```

Моя папка routes:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::post('/login',function(){
return view('login');
});

Route::post('/register',function(){
return view('register');
});

Route::post('/contact',function(){
return view('contact');
});

Route::get('/about',function(){
return view('about');
});

Route::get('/home', ['as' => 'home' , function(){
return view('index');
}]);
```

Если я убераю сам импорт то получаю Undefined на Route::get и так далее .. 
При попытке перехода в класс метода не могу найти сам метод , при переходе в Route который не содержит методов запроса , Route наследует от Facade , при переходе на Facade не нахожу методов запроса таких как get,post и так далее, с другой стороны при импорте данного use `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;` Php Shtorm перестаёт ругатся на Undefined, как так ? Если в самом импортируемом коде я не могу найти get,post etc ..

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы и не должны настраивать Router. Laravel изначально должен спокойно запускать страницы. Проблема может быть в том, что если вы делали проект в openServer, либо даже на локалке, то вы были обязаны создать отдельную папку под проект.Во вторых не трогайте и не удаляйте импорты фреймворка, только в крайних случаях(не в вашем), и не открывайте файлы в браузере что за бред???Про Mvc паттерн советую почитать ,вы получаете ошибки из за того, что  файл web.php и прочие подключения не работают как самостоятельные файлы, они взаимодействуют друг с другом, ваша задача проверять работу только в папке public.Вот пример:[image: введите сюда описание изображения] О боже у меня такая же ошибка! Но переходим в public:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]И все работает.В третьих если же вы не хотите видеть открытую папку с проектом в начале , и каждый раз не открывать папку public то создаете файл .htacess и пишете следующее:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

И еще раз советую изучить MVC паттерн, ибо не понимая как он работает, подобных глупых вопросов будет много.

Но основная ошибка говорит, что Laravel не может открыть лог для записи.
Поэтому попробуй :

```
php artisan cache:clear 

chmod -R 777 app/storage # для laravel < 5.4
chmod -R 777 storage/ # для laravel >= 5.4

composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: Знаю я как работает паттерн mvc причём тут этот патерн вообще ..
Речь идёт о настройках в ларавеле , на обычном пхп уже бы писал свододно

Comment: @Mekudad А вот это тогда к чему было?При попытке перехода в папку с routes > web.php в браузере по пути http://localhost/conlineltd/routes/web.php я получаю ошибку:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route' not found. Если вы такое пишите, значит вы не понимаете принцип работы MVC. Эти маршруты  выдают ошибку когда вы их открываете соло файлом в браузере, я привел пример где вы смотреть должны. Laravel сразу должен нормально работать.

Comment: Причём тут MVC парень я пишу на Java нормально Спринг и Хибернейт Используя MVC .. 
Ты прочитай про MVC может быть сам не до конца понимаешь что это .. Я первый раз сел за Ларавэл как и ожидалось возникли вопросы так что прошу не умничать .

Comment: @Mekudad Я не умничаю, я тебе уже сказал, Laravel работает по MVC схеме.Ты уверяешь, что понимаешь как он работает, но при этом(Я тебе уже писал и показал)задаешь глупый вопрос почему в браузере роуты у тебя ошибку выдают

Comment: Я понял что ты мне указал паренёк .. я загрузил проект через public и получил другую ошибку , ни как не могу понять причём тут MVC но ты можешь стоять на своём .. Настройки сервера на паблик я добавил с верху ..

Comment: @Mekudad Так и говори ошибку которая вылазит в public, я стою на своем потому, что ты указал на ошибку в файле web.php, когда в браузере открывал

Comment: Я её добавил к предидущему ответу но он был удалён .. 
The stream or file "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/conlineltd/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Comment: @Mekudad посмотри я внизу ответа дописал

Comment: к дополнению https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/file-permissions-for-laravel-5-and-others